# Review of document registrar

Tags: java

Would you be kind to make me a code review? It would be nice to have some comments, whether you would have done something differently and so on.  I am not sure about the way I handle the exception.  Is there a better way?

```
@Transactional
public classServiceImpl implements Service {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HermesServiceImpl.class);


    @Autowired(required = true)
    private Client client;

    @Autowired
    private SubmissionDAO submissionDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SubmissionSender hrsQueueSender;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void registerDocument(String submissionId) {

        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final List<HermesItem> items = submissionDAO.getSubmissionItems(submissionId);
        RegistrationSummary regSummary = null;

        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
            final HrsDocumentBuilder builder = new HrsDocumentBuilder();
            final Date docDate = new Date();
            builder.setTitle(submissionId);
            builder.setDocumentDate(docDate);
            builder.setSentDate(docDate);
            builder.setMailType(HermesMailType.INTERNAL);

            /* Document is constructed, try to invoke Hermes - upload annexes and register document. */
            try {
                regSummary = client.registerDocument(builder.buildDocument());
            } catch (final ClientException e) {
                LOG.error("Unable to register document with Submission Id= [" + submissionId + "], " + e.getMessage());
            }
            if (regSummary != null) {
                final String hermesDocId = regSummary.getHermesDocumentId();
                /* Update the DB with the documentID received from Hermes. */
                final int update = submissionDAO.updateSubmission(submissionId, hermesDocId, SubmissionStatus.HRS_REGISTERED.name());

                if (update < 1) {
                LOG.error("update error");
                }
            } else {
                submissionDAO.updateSubmission(submissionId, null, SubmissionStatus.HRS_FAILED.name());
                hrsQueueSender.sendMesage(submissionId);
            }

        } else {
            LOG.error("Not found");
            submissionDAO.updateSubmission(submissionId, null, SubmissionStatus.ANNEXES_NOT_FOUND.name());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points:

- Try to avoid long or nested if/else
- Sub-divide tasks in smaller functions(clean and more readable code + easier unit testing)
- Minimize variable scope(try to declare variables in the scope where you really need them)
- Think about Exception in context of your business domain, may be using builder pattern (like HrsDocumentBuilder) can be useful to have consistent logging message for same type of exception(**override toString() method**).

We can refactor the method **registerDocument()** like this:

You may replace

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

with [StopWatch](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html)

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void registerDocument(String submissionId) {
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();    
final List<HermesItem> items = submissionDAO.getSubmissionItems(submissionId);

if (!hasItems(items)) //extract else to method
    return;

final HrsDocumentBuilder builder = ...builder.setMailType(HermesMailType.INTERNAL);//stays the same
try {
      // minimized the scope of local variable, you need regSummary in try block so declare it here.
        RegistrationSummary regSummary = client.registerDocument(builder.buildDocument()); // will rename buildDocument() -> build() 
        update(regSummary);

} catch (final ClientException e) { 

       //To standarized log message we can refactor it like :
        ClientExceptionBuilder b = new ClientExceptionBuilder(e).submissionId(submissionId).build();// override toString()
        LOG.error(b.getMessage());
}
}//function registerDocument() end here
```

Since all other method can be easily extracted from else blocks, i am posting only the **update(regSummary)** because this function can be further subdivide into two smaller functions like this:

```
void update(regSummary) {

    if(!hasSummary()) //extract else to method 
        return 

    final String hermesDocId = regSummary.getHermesDocumentId();
    /* Update the DB with the documentID received from Hermes. */
    final int update = submissionDAO.updateSubmission(submissionId, hermesDocId, SubmissionStatus.HRS_REGISTERED.name());

    if (update < 1) 
        LOG.error("update error");

}
```